Input mismatch in dense layer
I am using this autoencoder model to detect anomaly.
class AnomalyDetector(Model):
  def __init__(self):
    super(AnomalyDetector, self).__init__()
    self.encoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
      layers.Dense(32, activation="relu", name = 'layer1'),
      layers.Dense(16, activation="relu", name = 'layer2'),
      layers.Dense(8, activation="relu", name = 'layer3')])

    self.decoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
      layers.Dense(16, activation="relu", name = 'layer4'),
      layers.Dense(32, activation="relu", name = 'layer5'),
      layers.Dense(140, activation="sigmoid", name = 'layer6')])

  def call(self, x):
    encoded = self.encoder(x)
    decoded = self.decoder(encoded)
    return decoded

autoencoder = AnomalyDetector()

autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mae')

But While fitting  it shows the following errors:
history = autoencoder.fit(X_train_credible, X_train_credible, 
          epochs=20, 
          batch_size=512,
          validation_data=(X_test, X_test),
          shuffle=True)


ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "sequential_12" "                 f"(type Sequential).
        
        Input 0 of layer "layer1" is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 140, but received input with shape (None, 1)
        
        Call arguments received by layer "sequential_12" "                 f"(type Sequential):
          • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 1), dtype=string)
          • training=False
          • mask=None
    
    
    Call arguments received by layer "anomaly_detector_6" "                 f"(type AnomalyDetector):
      • x=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 1), dtype=string)

The shape of X_train_credible is:
X_train_credible

<tf.Tensor: shape=(299634, 140), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[7292, 3197, 1580, ...,  623,  659, 1117],
       [6565, 1740, 3119, ...,    0,    0,    0],
       [6565, 1740, 3119, ...,    0,    0,    0],
       ...,
       [6565, 1740, 3119, ...,    0,    0,    0],
       [7292, 3197, 1580, ...,  623,  659, 1117],
       [6565, 1740, 3119, ...,    0,    0,    0]])>

I am new to TensorFlow. Anyone, please help me how to resolve this issue.
Thank you.

Do you want to use regression, e.g. your labels are shape (1,)? Then your last layer should also have only one node. Right now, your have 140 output values for a sample.

The error you're encountering is related to the shape of the input data you're providing to the model. The model expects the input shape to match what it was defined for in the encoder layers, but it seems like the actual input data shape doesn't match this expectation.The error message indicates that the first layer of your encoder is expecting an input with shape (None, 140), but it received an input with shape (None, 1). This suggests that your data might not be in the expected format or shape.

Make sure that X_train_credible and X_test are NumPy arrays or Tensors with the correct shape. It should be (number_of_samples, number_of_features). In your case, it looks like you have (299634, 140).Define the input shape explicitly when creating the Sequential model. This ensures that the first layer of your encoder knows the shape of the input it will receive.
